# How to find BMI Index Values and Weight status in C#?

Tags: c#

We want to write a program for BMI Index Values but have not succeeded. here is my code

```
int under = 0, nor = 0, over = 0, obes = 0;
int m, h; //MASS & HEIGHT
Console.Write("Please enter the mass in lbs :");
m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Please enter the height in inches :");
h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[, ] arr = new int[2, 20]; //2 dimensional array
Console.Write("HEIGHT :  ");
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
    arr[i, j] = h++;
    Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");
  }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++)
    arr[i + 1, j] = m++;
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("         ________");
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("MASS(lbs)");
Console.Write(arr[1, 0] + "      |");
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 19; j++) {
    int ibs = arr[1, 0] * 703 / (arr[i, j] * arr[i, j]); //FORMULA IBS
    if (ibs < 18.5) {
      under++;
      ibs = -1122;
      Console.Write(ibs + " ");
    } else if (ibs < 24.5) {
      nor++;
      Console.Write(ibs + " ");
    } else if (ibs < 29.9) {
      over++;
      ibs = 1122;
      Console.Write(ibs + " ");
    } else if (ibs > 30) {
      obes++;
      ibs = 0;
      Console.Write(ibs + " ");
    }
  }
}
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("TOTAL UNDERWEIGHT ARE:" + under);
Console.WriteLine("TOTAL NORMAL ARE :" + nor);
Console.WriteLine("TOTAL OVERWEIGHT ARE :" + over);
Console.WriteLine("TOTAL OBESE ARE :" + obes);
```

we need this output
[image]
and the following requirements for BMI Index Values.
Visual C# program for calculating body mass index (BMI)for a population with specific ranges, input mass in pounds and heights in inches, two-dimensional array used.

with following conditions

```
if (bmi < 18.5) {
      under++;
      bmi = -1122;
      Console.Write(bmi + " ");
    } else if (bmi < 24.5) {
      nor++;
      Console.Write(bmi + " ");
    } else if (bmi < 29.9) {
      over++;
      bmi = 1122;
      Console.Write(bmi + " ");
    } else if (bmi > 30) {
      obes++;
      bmi = 0;
      Console.Write(bmi + " ");
    }
```

But I am unable to get the output that I needed—only one line print.
i.e

```
MASS(lbs) 
170 |0 0 0 1122 1122 1122 1122 1122 1122 1122 1122 1122 1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122
```

Comment: You "didn't succeed", but what happened? What were your results, how do they differ from expected?

Comment: only one input comes 170, I think my programming loop logic is incorrect ??? @HansKeﬆing 
that is
MASS(lbs)
170      |0 0 0 1122 1122 1122 1122 1122 1122 1122 1122 1122 1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122 -1122

Comment: You don't have a Console.Write for <29.9. Suggestion: do a single write *after* those ifs.

Comment: sir @HansKeﬆing I edited my code above but the issue still not resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for-loop: `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)`  will only loop *once*, with i equal to 0. So you don't need that when you build `arr`. In fact you can combine those two initializing loops!

```
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) // note the j<20: I don't want to miss the highest index, 19.
{
    arr[0, j] = h++; // heights in row 0
    arr[1, j] = m++; // masses in row 1
    Console.Write(arr[0, j] + " ");
}
```

You are now using a two-dimensional array to store two unrelated lists of values. A better design would be to use two single-dimensional arrays: one for heights and another for weights. These might then have different lengths, if so desired.

In the print-loop, you want to iterate over all values in the first row (for the height) and also iterate over all values in the second row (for the mass).

```
Console.Write("MASS(lbs)");
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) // *all* values in row 0
{
    // start a new line, with a mass-header
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write(arr[1, i] + "      |");
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        int ibs = arr[1, i] * 703 / (arr[0, j] * arr[0, j]); //FORMULA IBS
        // etc
```

And one extra point: in your `else if (ibs > 30) {`, you don't want that "if", a plain `else` would be enough to catch anything that didn't match any of the previous "if"s. Also, if ibs came out to 29.93, it would just fall between the cracks (not <29.9 and also not >30).

**EDIT**
Not that you would *get* 29.93, as `ibs` has type `int`. Also you use integer division, which may lead to "rounding errors" (`5/3 == 1`).

Comment: yes I forgot loop outside of the formula